# create triggers on the payment table so that the amount column will always be set to a price that ends with 99 cents | mysql

Tags: sql

this is my task ->

> In the alikas database, create triggers on the payment table so that the amount column
> will always be set to a price that ends with 99 cents. For example, values like 0.99, 1.99,
> 2.99 are fine but values like 0.0, 2.1, 10.98 are not.
> Remember – The rule above must be enforced both for existing rows and for new rows.
> Include two DML statements. One that demonstrates a success and one that demonstrates
> failure.

After many attempts, this is what I was able to achieve:

[image: this is my attempt]

Comment: Add code please instead of sharing image.

Comment: Please also tag the dbms you're using. What's wrong with this code?